# need help removing time from a csv file

Tags: sed, awk, unix

im trying to process a csv and make it easier for sorting, and i need to remove the time and the dash from it. the file has entries like this:

```
James,07/20/2009-14:40:11
Steve,08/06/2006-02:34:37
John,11/03/2008-12:12:34
```

and parse it into this:

```
James,07/20/2009
Steve,08/06/2006
John,11/03/2008
```

im guessing sed is the right tool for this job?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -d '-' -f 1 file
```

Edit after comment:

```
sed 's/-[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]//g' file
```

Comment: what if the name contains a dash?

Comment: If the name is something like Al-Ashrad then the output will be Al, which is wrong, thank you for pointing that out. I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Python

```
import csv
import datetime

rdr = csv.reader( open("someFile.csv", "rb" ) )
rows = list( reader )
rdr.close()

def byDateTime( aRow ):
    return return datetime.datetime.strptime( aRow[1], "%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S" )

rows.sort( key= byDateTime )

wtr = csv.writer( open("sortedFile.csv", "wb" ) )
wtr.writerows( rows )
wtr.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

just use awk

```
awk -F"," '{ split($2,_,"-"); print $1,_[1] }' OFS="," file
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think sed is the right tool for the job:

```
sed 's/-[:0-9]*$//' file
```